# Android Studio: package name conflict and BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission error

Tags: android, package, android-permissions

I receive the following error in logcat when app crashes:

[image]

The app's package name is com.todo.quickcards

[image]

Somehow the RebootReceiver and RebootService classes have a reference to an old package name (see yellow highlights where the package name says "com.wimso.v118.RebootReceiver" and  "com.example.jdw.v118/com.wimso.v118.RebootService).  The logcat error suggests the BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission is needed in RebootService class but the Android Manifest already has that permission added for the RebootService:

```
AndroidManifest.xml
...
<service
        android:name="com.todo.quickcards.RebootService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="false"
        android:description="@string/rebootservicedesc" >
</service>
```

How can I remove the erroneous, old package name reference and have Android Studio reference the current com.todo.quickcards package name for the RebootReceiver and RebootService classes?

Comment: what you show on the image is not the app package name. It is stated in build.gradle.

Comment: So it is the applicationId?  If so, the current applicationId is "com.todo.quickcards."  So there is a bad reference somewhere that is not picking up the new applicationId. 
And somehow the Notifications are firing even though I am getting the logcat error.  Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that I had an earlier version of the app on my device and that version did not have the android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" in the Manifest.  So when the device was re-booted the Receiver and Service in the earlier version app were generating the permission error.  I updated the earlier version app with the BIND permission and no errors were generated.